# Killing Python script from sub function and updating Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, exception, aws-lambda

A bit of a odd problem, I have a long script which I want to error our in certain conditions. If I error out I want to stop there and then.

exit() doesnt work because lambda gets re triggered as it didn't get a response to say the script has ended successfully.

python 'return' doesn't work for me because it only returns to the parent function. At which point the code will continue running.

I am wondering how I can exit or 'return' all the way back to lambda that the script is considered complete without letting the script end?

My current approach is to throw an exception in my sub functions and wrap my main function in a try catch where the sub functions trigger that exception, that cant be the best way.

```
def kill_script():
     raise Exception(msg)

def do_something():
     kill_script() # pretend something has gone wrong. 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     try:     
         do_something()
     except: 
         print("this is how I currently do it, cant be the best way?")
```

Comment: If you have an exceptional output, then raise an exception there and then. You don't need a separate function to just raise an exception, raise the exception in your `do_something()` function. Also, don't use `try:` `except:` here, just call `do_something()` and if it fails the exception will be raised (which is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @HoboProber, you can raise another exception in your `do_something()`, and you can actually ultimately raise another exception in your `lambda_handler`'s try/except block. The AWS documentation mentions:

"If your Lambda function raises an exception, AWS Lambda recognizes the failure and serializes the exception information into JSON and returns it." See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-exceptions.html